# Dynamic programming find the number of all increasing subsequences ends with Xj in given sequence for every index j

Tags: algorithm, recursion, sequence, dynamic-programming

Given a sequence of real numbers (X1, X2, ..., Xn). Write an algorithm as efficient there is, that finds the number of strictly increasing sub-sequences for every index j, that end with Xj.

(A strictly increasing sub-sequence is defined: Xa1, Xa2, ..,Xai when a1 < a2 .. < ai, maintains: Xa1 < Xa2 < .. < Xai. the sub-sequence ends with Xj if ai = j)

My solution should include a recurrence formula that solves this problem in `O(n^2)` and a correctness proof, I was only able to solve it using a nested for loop and I'm not sure if there's an `O(n^2)` recursion solution.

```
List a[1…n] <- [1…1]
 For j= 1 to n
    For i= 1 to j-1
       If xi<xj then
          a[i]= a[j]+a[i];
```

Comment: What do you want then?

Comment: recursion/memorization style of answer

Comment: Sorry, you cannot just vandalise your post. The question plus answer is a combined work licensed under the CC wiki license.

Comment: This guy took back his acceptance on my solution after he found he cannot delete this question...lol

Answer (score 0):

When you do `a[i] = a[j] + a[i]`, you are actually just doing `a[i]++`, since  `a[j]==1` each time you run that line.  If this is not immediately obvious, you should trace the execution of your code by hand and see what it is actually doing.

What you probably wanted:

```
for j in range(n):
    for i in range(j):
        if x[i] < x[j]:
            a[j] += a[i]
```

The recurrence relation is:
the number of increasing subsequences ending at `j` is the sum over the number of increasing subsequences ending at every index less than `j`, plus 1 for the sequence containing just `j`.

**Analysis**

This is an O(n^2) solution.  Proof: the first iteration of the outer loop, we loop 1 times in the inner loop (the inner loop does a constant amount of computation each iteration).  Each time we increment j, we increment the number of iterations in the inner loop.  So we end up calling the code inside the inner loop a total of 
`1 + 2 + 3 + ... (n-1) + n` times.  Let `f(n) = 1 + 2 + 3 + ... n`.

Recall the [definition](http://xlinux.nist.gov/dads/HTML/bigOnotation.html) of big-O: f(n) = O(n^2) means there are positive constants `c` and `k`, such that `0 ≤ f(n) ≤ cn^2` for all `n ≥ k`. The values of `c` and `k` must be fixed for the function f and must not depend on `n`.

Clearly `0 ≤ f(n)` so we just need to show that there exists some `c` and `k` such that `f(n) ≤ cn^2` for all `n ≥ k`.  I will choose `c=1` and `k=1`.  You can verify that `f(n) <= n^2` for all `n`.

Although you didn't ask, your comment below suggests you want proof that this is the *tightest* bound we can get.  So I will prove that `f(n) = Ω(n^2)`

[`f(n)=Ω(n^2)`](http://blog.computationalcomplexity.org/2005/01/big-omega.html) if for some constant `c>0` and all large enough n, `f(n) ≥ cn^2`.

Let us pick `c=4`.  Then we have `f(n) = 1 + 2 + 3 + ... n >= (n/2) + (n/2)+1 + (n/2)+2 + ... n`, where we just subtracted `1 + 2 + ... (n/2)-1` from `f(n)` to get this inequality.

Also, `(n/2) + (n/2)+1 + (n/2)+2 + ... n >= (n/2)*(n/2)` since we can take all `n/2` terms which are `>= n/2` and lower-bound them by exactly `n/2` each.

But `(n/2)*(n/2) = (n^2)/4`, so we have `f(n) >= (1/4)n^2` for all n, so we have shown that `f(n) = Ω(n^2)`.

Comment: Does this answer count as a dynamic programming style? I was trying to solve it using a recursion. I'm not sure what you meant by, a[j] += a[i], could you please explain? Thanks

Comment: That is shorthand for `a[j] = a[j] + a[i]`.

Comment: This definitely counts as dynamic programming, since to solve for `a[j]`, we use information that we have already computed for `a[j-1], a[j-2] ... a[1]`.  Is there any reason you must use recursion?  Usually things are done iteratively when doing DP since we need to store intermediate results.

Comment: What's the benefit of this approach compared to the OP's one? It is basically the same code with an extra syntatic sugar (that does not exist in all languages)

Comment: This code increments the variable in the outer loop, instead of the inner loop.  In fact, OP's solution is incorrect.  For `n=2, Input = [1, 2]`, it will return `answer=[2,1]`.  But it should return `[1,2]`.

Comment: James, could you help me with the recurrence formula for your attached example?

Comment: I compared both supplied solutions, something is not right in this solution as its output is: [4, 2, 1, 18, 2, 10, 20, 43, 41, 147, 127, 254, 40, 121, 285], here is the code snippet: https://repl.it/vRL/1, while the CPP version returns a totally other output: http://cpp.sh/6ajs, [0, 1, 1, 0, 2, 6, 12, 24, 24, 0, 0, 0, 24, 72, 168]

Comment: Ignore my last comment please

Comment: is it possible to formulate a recurrence formula for this approach?

Comment: @TCP_Explorer, I explained the recurrence relation in my post.  Just translate it to a formula.

Comment: this is a O(j^2), not O(n^2). you shouldn't run from j in range n but in range j.

Comment: @TCP_Explorer, see updated post on complexity analysis.  It can't be O(j^2) since j is a variable I introduced in the algorithm itself...

Answer (score 0):

So basically you want a Top-Down approach?
How about this?

```js
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int dp[15] = {0};
int a[15] = {3,2,1,14,2,4,5,9,7,20,12,13,6,8,11};

int DP(int x){
 if(x == 0) return 1;
 if(dp[x]) return dp[x];
 int ret = 1;
 for(int i=0; i<x; i++) if(a[x] > a[i]) ret += DP(i);
 return dp[x] = ret;
}
int main(){
 printf("%d\n", DP(14));
 return 0; 
}
```

The recurrence formula is the same, it's not dependent of how you implement the solution (Top Down or Bottom Up)

Here it is:

[image]

Comment: could you elaborate? "if(dp[x]) return dp[x];" why is this necessary?

Comment: And does this run on O(N^2)?

Comment: @TCP_Explorer `if(dp[x]) return dp[x]` is what prevents this from running in exponential time, recomputing DP(i) each time we need it in computing `DP(i+1)`, `DP(i+2)`, etc.  This line says if we already computed `dp[x]`, just look it up in the table and return it.
Also, this runs in O(n^2), since for each `x`, we need to sum up values for every `i<x`.

Comment: @TCP_Explorer I thought you know what is "memorization"...For deatails you can refer to James ' explanation above...

Comment: I do know, got it now! shouldn't you set dp[15] = {1}? as each element is a sub sequence itself.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding your cpp code. "return dp[x] = ret;" what does that do other then setting ret into dp[x]?. If I set dp[x] = {1} the if(dp[x]) condition will always throw "True".

Comment: so u dont know memorization...dp[x] will set to true only if it is calculated before, so return it's value directly instead of go into the for loop and make massive call to its subproblems...otherwise it will be exponential running time

Comment: I meant that if we set dp[15] = {1} it will always be true, but you pointed the ret = 1 which explains what you did instead of initializing it with '1'. could you care to explain the last return? "return dp[x] = ret;" this will return both ret and assign ret to the last index?

Comment: this will FIRST assign the value of ret to dp[x], then return dp[x] as result of the function...note that now dp[x] must be at least 1, so all call to this subproblem afterwards can get its value directly  at the line  if(dp[x]) return dp[x]...

Comment: I compared both supplied solutions, I think that something is not right, for the input supplied this is the dp array at the end:  [1, 0, 2, 6, 12, 24, 24, 0, 0, 0, 24, 72, 168], source: http://cpp.sh/6ajs, the second solution returns another output for the same input. output: [4, 2, 1, 18, 2, 10, 20, 43, 41, 147, 127, 254, 40, 121, 285], source: http://cpp.sh/6ajs

Comment: please ignore my last comment

Comment: and what part makes you not accepting this solution?

Comment: accepted. would appreciate if you can help me with the recurrence formula. Thanks!